# Infinitely many simple closed geodesics in any compact orientable surface but the sphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces, geodesics, closed-geodesic

My question is the following: if $(\Sigma, g)$ is any compact orientable Riemannian surface of genus $g \geq 1$, is it true that there are infinitely many closed, simple and geometrically distinct geodesics in $(\Sigma, g)$? Maybe this holds for a generic set of Riemannian metrics?

I found the following theorem, due to Klingenberg and Takens:

> Let $M$ be a compact smooth manifold. There is a dense set of metrics on $M$ such that every metric in this set admits infinitely many non trivial, geometrically distinct closed geodesics.

However, it is not clear if the geodesics in the theorem are simple.

Added: by simple geodesic I mean a geodesic without self-intersections.

Comment: Are they geometrically distinct?

Comment: If two simple geodesics $\gamma, \eta$ are not geometrically distinct then one may be reparameterized to give the other, and in particular either $\gamma = \eta$ in the fundamental group or $\gamma = \eta^{-1}$. So if the free homotopy classes are distinct and no two are inverse to one another, then yes, they are all geometrically distinct.

Comment: @MikeMiller by geometrically distinct I mean no two of them can be related by an isometry.

Comment: Interesting!! They are all simple?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I found this existence theorem for geodesics in conjugacy classes of the fundamental group, but no information of whether the obtained geodesics are simple is given.

Comment: @Alexandre: Can this loop be removed without changing the homotopy class? In principle the loop could be non-contractible, no?

Comment: Although the title suggests otherwise, the paper `Examples of Embedded Minimal Tori
without Area Bounds' by Colding--Minicozzi might be of interest. In the first section the authors prove that for any closed surface $\Sigma$, there is an open set of metrics that admit arbitrarily long embedded closed geodesics.

Comment: Reviving this question but I believe the answer is no. If you take the sphere but perturb the 3 axes to be different lengths, then there are only 3 closed, simple geodesics. I believe the argument is due to Brian white but am unable to find a source. Though see the discussion after Corollary 1.7 in these notes:
http://web.stanford.edu/~ochodosh/MCFnotes.pdf